# Drupal exposed filter theming

Tags: views, theming

Is there a way to show views exposed filter with in betweeen operator for integer type as a select list(0-10, 10-20, etc)?

Comment: To be enoughst this question is far from being theming, because the actual behaviour would have to be changed. In general currently you would have to write a custom field handler, to achieve what you need. There are some tutorials out there. In theory one day http://drupal.org/node/731662 would allow you to configure this directly in views, but the patch is not ready yet and also not commited yet. Additional if you create a post here, please always add the drupal/views version, because it's often quite helpful.

Comment: A version still hasn't been indicated, but if someone stumbles upon this and is looking to do this in Drupal 6, there is a tutorial to walk you through it at http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-make-range-selector-filter-views

Answer (score 1):

1. You can alter your exposed form and print needle select list.
2. Than you hide your exposed filter with betweeen operator. E.g. display:none.
3. Than you write js that fills your hidden filter when user change select value.